# Selecting one vertex from each edge

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

This is a straightforward problem to explain and yet I'm having some tough time on figuring out a solution. My favorite kind!

Let G=(V,E) be a **bipartite** graph. I need to compute the minimum subset V' such that for every edge e=(u,v), **u belong to V' OR v belong to V'**. 
If there is more than one solution, anyone is acceptable.

|V| <= 2000

|E| <= 10000

Any hint could be useful :D

Comment: Homework? If so please tag it.

Comment: Does *e* include every edge in *E*?

Comment: It is not homework @Jacob, I'm just trying old programming contest exercises because I enjoy doing so. ;)
This one is from an old ACM ICPC regional.

Comment: Yes, I meant for every edge in E. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Konig's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29) is relevant.

Comment: Wow! Now is a maximum flow problem! Thanks!